# Writing Xuanhuan, but when did men start to wear Veil Hat's?

Tags: history, martial-arts

I dug into the whole Veil Hat thing in Chinese history, but I have come across a small problem. The weimao or mili seems only ever to be used by women. So I wonder if it would be accurate to have my main character, who is male, wear one. In most Wuxia or Xuanhuan stories, you seem high noble men and women wearing such fashion, so I'm wondering where men picked up women's fashion in history or if it's just an aesthetics thing.

Provide details and any research
The weimao was used mainly in the Sui and early Tang periods of Chinese history, while the mili became popular during the Sui dynasty. In all sources that I looked up, they only ever talk about women wearing them to show modesty, virtue and to protect their elaborate make-up from the wind and dust.

I would love some sources or references to history books on Chinese men picking up this fashion; I want to make sure I have my facts straight.

Comment: Mili veil hats were initially worn by men in [Tuyuhun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuyuhun) as a practical article of clothing, somewhat similar to the habit of Touareg men to wear veils; only later were such hats adopted by women as fashion items. But anyway, [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this question about real-world historical details.

Comment: Regardless of where this question ends up, welcome to worldbuilding, enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when. See you around.

Comment: I don't think this should necessarily be closed. If I understand right, xuanhuan is a kind of fantasy genre, thus applicable here. Just be aware, Jacky, as it's *amateurishly* bad form to demand that respondents "provide details and research".  You're not paying anywhere near enough to get away with that kind of talk! You've done some of your own research already, which is fantastic! It might be helpful if you could provide a little context about the world & culture your story is set in: is this an invented world, alt-hist Earth or a fantasy Earth? Some comparative context would be  excellent!

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I didn't mean to make it sound like I was demanding detailed research. I'll be sure to watch my wording the next time I ask a question! (Whoops enter posted my reply before I was ready.)

The background of the story is set in a fantasy setting, I know for a fact that I would never be able to do justice to Chinese history if I tried to shoehorn that in. My main inspiration for the story I am writing is from the Volcanic Age and Heaven's Offical Blessing. I wanted to do my own twist on the xuanhuan setting, and I was confused by some of the fashion choices.

Comment: Xuanhuan settings (and other similar genres) do not follow historical fashion accurately (hairstyles are especially far from historical examples). If you saw the Untamed, you should've noticed that each clan's outfit is loosely based on a different dynasty. In BL (as in HOB) men often wear androgynous or even feminine outfits.

Comment: @JackytheAmateur You can edit your question and reword or add details as needed from the comments, 'specially if it doesn't invalidate the answers :).

Comment: @elemtilas After [my Meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8488/40609), do you still think this shouldn't be closed? It appears the OP is looking for confirmation that in Real Life something was gender-specific, which is contrary to the gender he wants to use, and (if I read between the lines correctly), that means the something won't be used if true. In other words, no world rule is being discussed. This appears to be a pure history question with no actual worldbuilding context.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact -- Thanks for bringing this back to mind! I reread this query & my comment on it in the context of your Meta post & my response to it. My perspective now is: yes this query should be closed. Rationale: sadly, it's been over two months and the OP has not provided any kind of edit to the question that would provide sufficient worldbuilding context. We just have the tantalising teasers of heavenly blessing and volcanic ages. I think it's clear from comments that the fantasy genre in question doesn't strictly follow historical sex/gender conventions, and it's also clear ...

Comment: ... that the question isn't really about those sex/gender conventions per se. As I understand the question as written, OP is asking for permission to do X within a fantasy genre while seemingly referring to real world historical trends. If I read Otkin's comment right, he seems to be granting permission, because real history doesn't figure on the one hand, and real xuanhuan do exactly what the OP wants to do on the other. I'd still have liked to see this question edited for fictional world context because right ...

Comment: ... now it's basically an opinion based query with neither sufficient context nor worldbuilding dependency. Otkin's comment is therefore as close to a 5 star answer as this question deserves as written.